# DB2 EXP() command returning arithmetic overflow

Tags: exception, db2, overflow, arithmetic-expressions

Hi I am using the EXP() command in DB2 on a column of type float as so

```
select distinct 1 - power(0.9144,exp(beta - 0.1)) from mytable
```

where this all works fine until I introduce the exp() around (beta - 0.1). beta is a float and ranges between 3018.878989897931 and 12289.951602012534.

the error I am getting is

```
Arithmetic overflow or other arithmetic exception occurred.. SQLCODE=-802,SQLSTATE=22003,DRIVER=3.64.106
```

what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the issue here is your exceeding the maximum range representable by a 64-bit floating point number format, which is about +1.79769E+308.

If you do need to work with larger numbers, consider performing calculations in `DECFLOAT(34)` instead (if your DB2 version supports this data type).